# NuxtJS: nuxt got 500 error when refresh page or go directly to specific route

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I have a page that I get the desired data from within the page using asyncData. When I go to this page from the home page, there is no problem, but if I refresh the same page, the page gets error 500.
in my project SSR is TRUE
and this is my code:

```
import { GetPriceDetails } from "@/services";


  asyncData({ params }) {
    return GetPriceDetails.getDetails(params.coinName).then(
      (res) => {
        return {
          coinData: res.data.data,
        };
      }
    );
  },
```

[image]

I've change `target` to `static` and try `npm run generate`
that point is this issue occure on `localhost` not `production server`

Comment: your error says that you are trying to access a `status` property of an undefined object somewhere but you didn't include that code

Comment: actually, this is not true. because when it is supposed to get data from the backend and I implement in asyncData hook, if refresh the page or goes directly to the page, asyncData does not call, so there is no data to find the status of undefined something. in other hand there is no  asyncData  when refresh page

Answer (score 0):

I still think we need to see where that part is failing, but also try it with async/await

```js
async asyncData({ params }) {
  const coinData = (await GetPriceDetails.getDetails(params.coinName).data;
  return { coinData };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem related to SSR.

Try to wrap the inside of your template with the client only tag.

https://nuxt.com/docs/api/components/client-only#clientonly

```
<template>
 <ClientOnly>
 
  ..content

 </ClientOnly>
</template>
```

You could also disable SSR for testing:
in nuxt.config.ts add

```
ssr: false
```

Answer (score 0):

setting nuxt.config.js

```
ssr:false
```

resolved the issue for me